# Change direction of multidimensional html list layering

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve an effect similar to the jsfiddle below. I would like to layer an HTML list in the opposite direction as it's default.

The goal is to get the parent list elements to appear as if they are above the child list elements. In the fiddle there is margin top on the child element to better show the box shadow. My goal is to change the `margin-top` from `5px` to `-5px` and have that child item appear below the parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/cepDd/

Is this something that is achievable? I have tried some things with z index to no avail. I tried to use absolute positioning but that did not seem to work very well either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-indexing will only work when you set the `position` property. Setting it to `relative` will do in this case.

[See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/HemzV/) based on your code.

Note: I have set the margin to 0px instead of 5px, so the child tucks below the parent. I suggest you use `padding-top` instead of `margin-top` to get more spacing

Comment: Aha, the position property was the missing link to getting the z-index working. I added a background color of #fff to your fiddle to add to the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand the goal.  The child is already 'below' the parent.  If you mean 'behind', you could set the opacity of the child

```
 opacity: 0.5;
```

[A FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/xqaaf/) that demonstrates